# How to integrate Java Wildfly Swarm applications with Sentry?

Tags: java, sentry, wildfly-swarm

We have a Java [Wildfly Swarm](https://docs.thorntail.io/2018.5.0/) application and I'm trying to configure it to report [Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/modules/jul/) events.

Referenced versions:

- **Wildfly BOM**: org.wildfly.bom:wildfly-javaee7:10.1.0.Final
- **Swarm Plugin**: org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2017.12.1

I added the following configurations:

```
<!-- pom.xml -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
   <artifactId>sentry</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.13</version>
</dependency>

# project-defautls.yml
swarm:
  logging:
    pattern-formatters:
      LOG_FORMATTER:
        pattern: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p (%t) [%c.%M()] %s%e%n"
    console-handlers:
      CONSOLE:
        named-formatter: LOG_FORMATTER
        level: INFO
    custom-handlers:
      SENTRY:
        module: com.sentry.jul
        attribute-class: io.sentry.jul.SentryHandler
        named-formatter: LOG_FORMATTER
        level: INFO
    root-logger:
      handlers:
      - CONSOLE
      - SENTRY

<!-- module.xml -->
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.sentry.jul">
    <resources>
        <artifact name="io.sentry:sentry:1.7.13" />
    </resources>
</module>

# Environment variable
SENTRY_DSN=***********
```

The application starts normally, but the following code snippet is not generating Sentry events:

```
try {
  throw new Exception("Testing...");
} catch(Exception e) {
  logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "ERROR {0}", e.getMessage());
}
```

By other hand, it works fine when I configure Sentry by [code](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/usage/) and generate an event:

```
Sentry.init(System.getenv("SENTRY_DSN"));
SentryClient sentry = SentryClientFactory.sentryClient();
try {
  throw new Exception("Testing...");
} catch(Exception e) {
  sentry.sendException(e);
}
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: If you log at DEBUG level (not to Sentry but to your normal logger) does it say anything initializing Sentry, or about an appender not being located?

Comment: I wonder where does the `com.sentry.jul` module come from. The `io.sentry:sentry:1.7.13` artifact certainly doesn't ship a `module.xml`.

Comment: I added `com.sentry.jul` as a jboss module in `src/main/resources`. If we don't provide a module, then application startup fails. I'm going to update this question to make it clear.

Comment: No log debugging message is shown

Comment: I'm trying to debug the code of `io.sentry.jul.SentryHandler` inside my Eclipse IDE to see what is going on. I set four breakpoints in [the publish method](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/blob/v1.7.13/sentry/src/main/java/io/sentry/jul/SentryHandler.java#L96-L111) at lines 98, 99, 105 and 107. The debugger reaches only the first one. It is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the code I realized my module definition was incomplete. I had to add other artifacts and dependencies:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.sentry.jul">
    <resources>
        <artifact name="io.sentry:sentry:1.7.13" /> 
        <artifact name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.7" />
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api" />
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" />
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Also I noticed there is no need to keep a project dependency to Sentry.

That's all!